# How do I apply a custom font system-wide for all users?

Tags: nautilus, fonts, root

I have installed the 'Droid' font.

[image]

The left one root nautilus, the right one normal nautilus. Why are the fonts different? (specifically look at menus)

I want both windows to use the same font.

Am I wrong? I got "droid" folder from Elementary OS and pasted it into `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid` and selected the font with Tweak Tool.

Answer (score 3):

Well, to set this font for the root account you have to run Tweak Tool as root and set the font there once again. Root account has has its own settings, different ones from your user account.

You don't have to manually copy fonts to system locations, `droid` fonts are already packaged for Ubuntu (at least 12.10), you can install them by entering following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-droid
```

Comment: I did what you sad but nothing changed. As root it seems already proper. But as non-root my user account font doesn't seem proper. I want the as the left ones font everywhere.

Comment: The correct one is the left one. (as root)

Comment: Have you selected the font, with Gnome Tweak Tool as *your* user?, What if you move the font to your .fonts folder in your home?.

Comment: I selected the font for both root and my user. I copied droid folder to my ".fonts" folder. Still the same. This issue is in only the nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy, you can achieve this task by install `gconf-editor`

1. Install `gconf-editor`, this can be installed via the [Ubuntu Software Center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gconf-editor)
2. Open up gconf-editor from the dash
3. Go to `/ -> apps -> nautilus -> preferences`
   [image: An image of gconf-editor showing the nautilus font setting]
4. Double-click the `desktop_font` preference, and change it to your liking. The format of the setting is `$font $size`
5. Restart your computer.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. What's wrong? http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/306/adszcy.png

Comment: @v-s-l Where is the font installed? It may need to be put in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`? Also, you need to restart nautilus for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I gave up ubuntu. So no issues left. I'll come back maybe later.